# why is my code for comparing the triplet ,hackerman problem , exceeding the time limit for some test cases?

Tags: arrays, compare, time-complexity

```
int* compareTriplets(int a_count, int* a, int b_count, int* b, int* result_count) 
{
    *result_count=2;
    int *r=(int*)calloc(2,sizeof(int));
    int i;
    i=0;
    while(i<3)
    {
        if(a[i]>b[i])
        {
            r[0]+=1;
        }
        else if(a[i]<b[i])
        {
            r[1]+=1;
        
        }
        else
        {
            continue;
        }
        i++;
    }
return r;
}
```

'a and b are two array pointers pointing to two array.if element at ith position of either array is greater than the other then one is incremented for the respective array in the new array r.the first position of r array is for a array and second poasition is for b array'

Answer (score 0):

If in a test case, `a[i] == b[i]`, then the `else` statement is reached, where you `continue` to the next loop iteration, without getting to `i++`. This causes an infinite loop.